# useNavigate outside functional component - react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

Is there a way to use useNavigate() hook outside functional component in react-router v6? I'm trying to use navigate(url) inside a saga function. I know in v4 we could do something like this:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
function* sagaFunc(){
 history.push(url)
}
```

Can we pass useNavigate() hook to do something similar outside component in react-router v6?

Comment: This behavior works but for some reason, it just changes the route and doesn't load the component. I have been trying to find a replacement for the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of to be able to use some routing functionality outside the react component.

```js
window.history.pushState({}, "Dashboard", "/dashboard");
window.location.reload();
```

I myself haven't found any suitable replacement for the `createBrowserHistory()` which existed in `v4` and `v5`.

Reference taken from [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/8241)

Comment: unfortunately, you can't pass the state through this way :(